# How does System V IPC deal with fragmentation when allocating a large block of memory using "shmget"?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, operating-system, kernel

I'm allocating a large block of shared memory using shmget on an embedded system:

```
shmid = shmget(key, 16777216, IPC_CREAT | 0666)
```

The system is running uClinux (2.6.28 Linux Kernel) using Slab allocator. I've got no MMU on the CPU.

Once in a while, when running the above shmget command, I get a page allocation failure. This also happens when I'm running out of available RAM, but this also happens once in a while when I have plenty of RAA available.

I suspect the culprit is fragmentation, but I'm not quite sure - so my questions is, can this error be caused because the IPC subsystem requires a continuous physical 16Mb segment for this procedure, and cannot find one due to fragmented memory, throwing the allocation failure, or does the issue lie elsewhere?

Comment: If this is due to fragmentation, your kernel log will have something along the lines of `page allocation failure: order x`, and a few lines below a list of free memory chunks: `x*4Kb y*8Kb z*16Kb ...` and so on. "Order" is the number of bits you shift the pagesize to get the size of the allocation.

Comment: @ninjalj yup, that's the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `!MMU` system, you do not have virtual memory, so your supposition is correct - a contiguous block of physical memory is required for that mapping.

You can alleviate this issue by refactoring your application to use multiple smaller shared memory blocks, and/or first allocating the shared memory as early as possible after boot.

Comment: I didn't think of allocating the segment immediately upon boot. This might be a viable solution, although this will be a memory hog.